# Find out the height of an element would have to animate max-height properly

Tags: jquery, css

We basically want to animate an element which currently has currently set

my.css file:

```
#stuff {
    max-height: 70px
}
```

to `max-height: auto`.

```
$('#stuff').animate({'max-height': 'auto'});
```

is not working - which makes sense as of course 'auto' is not a number.

The points is: If I would set `max-height: auto` the div has some calculated height (as seen in Chrome Developer tools) of around 200px - but as the content can be edited, I can not hard code this.

If I use a fixed value like

```
$('#stuff').animate({'max-height': 200});
```

this works - but what if the content of the div becomes better (can be edited in CMS).

Is there a way to determine the height the div would have with `max-height: auto` (around 200px) and then use this value to properly animate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to do is on DOM ready, calculate the actual height of the div as such:

```
$(function () {
    var $stuff = $('#stuff');
    var height = $stuff.clone().css({
        position: 'absolute', // hide this cloned element
        left: '-10000px',
        maxHeight: 'none' // clear the max-height set by CSS
    }).appendTo('body').height();

    $stuff.animate({
        maxHeight: height
    });
});
```

See it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abduncan/d2QfV/)

Answer (score 1):

### My current Workaround:

The #stuff element contains two nested divs:

```
<div id="stuff">
    <div id="a">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div id="b">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

I am now using `$('#a').outerWidth() + $('#b').outerWidth()` to calculate the height I need. (`cHeight` in Ross' answer)

### Better approach:

An option might be to

1. duplicate the full #stuff div
2. make it display none
3. remove the max-height property (max-height: auto)
4. then use `cHeight = $('#stuff-duplicate').height()'

Comment: Great to see you found an approach.